# Cant figure out why I'm getting an error creating DB tables

Tags: javascript, sql, express, mariadb

I can not for the life of me figure out why my create table code does not work properly. I'm running express/js/sql to create tables and providing foreign constraint keys but one of them gives me an error with the keys

I cannot change the order as the tables are needed in that order for the foreign keys, it works completely fine If I remove the ALARM foreign key but I need to include it. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

I have this code and when creating it, the alarm table does not create.

```
let records = [ 
  "create table IF NOT EXISTS FILE (cal_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, file_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, version INT NOT NULL, prod_id VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)", 
  "create table IF NOT EXISTS EVENT (event_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, summary VARCHAR(1024), start_time DATETIME NOT NULL, location VARCHAR(60), organizer VARCHAR(256), cal_file INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(cal_file) REFERENCES FILE(cal_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)", 
  "create table IF NOT EXISTS ALARM (alarm_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, action VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, `trigger` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, event INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(event) REFERENCES FILE(event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)"
];
```

I call it like this

```
for (let rec of records) {
    db.query(rec, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log("Something went wrong. "+err);
    });
}
```

The error that I get is 
Something went wrong. Error: ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE: Can't create table `test`.`ALARM` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

last query should be, you are referencing FILE for foreign key instead of EVENT

```
  "create table IF NOT EXISTS ALARM (alarm_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, action VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, `trigger` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, event INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(event) REFERENCES FILE(event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)"
```

Comment: Wow i literally spent an hour looking at it, was pulling hairs almost, thank you for that, rookie mistake on my end.